# Parse JSON array response using Retrofit & Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

Here is my JSONArray Response from Web service:

```
[
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000067",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "AUBRY"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000171",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "PERRY"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000066",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "ARROYO"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000223",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "BARRETT"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000312",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "STECK"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000180",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "RIVERA"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000114",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "GOTTFRIED"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000091",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "COOK"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000126",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "JAFFEE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000327",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "DAVILA"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000144",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "LUPARDO"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": null,
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "SEPULVEDA",
        "committee_id": null
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000290",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "MOSLEY"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000167",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "ORTIZ"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000170",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "PEOPLES-STOKES"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000221",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "SKARTADOS"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000216",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "QUART"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000208",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "WEPRIN"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000186",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "ROSENTHAL"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000139",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "LIFTON"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000064",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "ABINANTI"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000173",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "PRETLOW"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000339",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "BICHOTTE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": null,
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "BARRON",
        "committee_id": null
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000341",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "WALKER"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000355",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "BLAKE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000185",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "RODRIGUEZ"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000259",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "FAHY"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000203",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "TITONE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000286",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "MCDONALD"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000081",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "CAHILL"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000421",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "HARRIS"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000338",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "JOYNER"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000448",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "JENNE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000070",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "BENEDETTO"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000310",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "SOLAGES"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000357",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "RICHARDSON"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000324",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "PICHARDO"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000423",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "HYNDMAN"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000313",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "STIRPE"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000131",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "KAVANAGH"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000204",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "TITUS"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000275",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "KIM"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000195",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "SIMOTAS"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000293",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "OTIS"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000220",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "MAYER"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000344",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "JEAN-PIERRE"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NYB00099404"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000113",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Vainieri Huttle, Valerie"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NJB00038817"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000208",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "WEPRIN"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NYB00066288"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000083",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Jasey, Mila M."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000086",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Caputo, Ralph R."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000046",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Watson Coleman, Bonnie"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000177",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Pintor Marin, Eliana"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000164",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Sumter, Shavonda E."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000104",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Oliver, Sheila Y."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000095",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Mainor, Charles"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000165",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Wimberly, Benjie E."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000016",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Fuentes, Angel"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000085",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Tucker, Cleopatra G."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000067",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Stender, Linda"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000114",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Johnson, Gordon M."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000082",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "McKeon, John F."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000129",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Singleton, Troy"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NJB00030216"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000088",
        "official_type": "SPONSOR",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Clark"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000171",
        "official_type": "COSPNSR",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Perry"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NYB00035573"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000111",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Schaer, Gary S."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000018",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Lampitt, Pamela R."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000105",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Giblin, Thomas P."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000171",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Mosquera, Gabriela M."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000011",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Moriarty, Paul D."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000165",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Wimberly, Benjie E."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000010",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Madden, Fred H."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000007",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Sweeney, Stephen M."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000039",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Thompson, Samuel D."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000112",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Weinberg, Loretta"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000087",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Ruiz, M. Teresa"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NJB00021785"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NYL000138",
        "official_type": "SPONSOR",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Lentol"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NYB00010409"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000028",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Gove, DiAnne C."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000027",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Rumpf, Brian E."
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000099",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Prieto, Vincent"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NJB00002928"
  },
  {
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000094",
        "type": "primary",
        "name": "Chiappone, Anthony"
      },
      {
        "leg_id": "NJL000034",
        "type": "cosponsor",
        "name": "Angelini, Mary Pat"
      }
    ],
    "id": "NJB00010952"
  }
]
```

Here is ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("bills/")
    Call<SponsorsResult> getListOfSponsors(@Query("bill_id") String billId , @Query("session") String session, @Query("fields") String field);

}
```

And here is call of method & response :

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<SponsorsResult> call = apiService.getListOfSponsors(AppConstants.ASSEMBLY_BILL_ID,AppConstants.SESSION,AppConstants.FIELD);
call.enqueue(new Callback<SponsorsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SponsorsResult> call, Response<SponsorsResult> response) {

        Log.d(TAG,"Number :" + response.raw());
        List<Sponsor> sponsors = response.body().getSponsors();
        Log.d(TAG,"Number of sponsors :" + sponsors.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SponsorsResult> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

As of now it fails & here is logcat output :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

It fails to execute response . Guide me to parse this response.

Comment: make sure you call this api ......... is confirm..?

Comment: I have updated my question . Please go through it.

Comment: something wrong on your parsing class with your response... format please recheck ..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Please try to use this one

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/sponsors")
    Call<List<SponsorsResult>> getStatesAndDistrict(
            @Field("xyz") String field1
    );



   Call <List<SponsorsResult>> call = service.getSponsorsValue();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SponsorsResult>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SponsorsResult>> call, Response<List<SponsorsResult>> response) {

            List<SponsorsResult> rs = response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SponsorsResult>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });



 class SponsorsResult {

    @SerializedName("sponsors")
    private List<SponsorsValue> sponsors;

    public List<SponsorsValue> getSponsors() {
        return sponsors;
    }
}

class SponsorsValue{
    @SerializedName("leg_id")
    @Expose
    private String legId;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getLegId() {
        return legId;
    }

    public void setLegId(String legId) {
        this.legId = legId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: These intermediary objects are usually referred as Data Transformation Objects, DTOs - so just keep in mind if you ever need to search further about these.

Comment: Hi there, I have the same issue, I did as outlined above, and I am indeed getting several SponsorResult objects as a list, however, how do I extract the SponsorValue objects out of this afterwards? I tried to do so and I only receive null, as a result, what am I doing wrong? can someone give me an example on extracting the corresponding object's fields?

Comment: Works perfectly 

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is. if your JSON response starts with a JSON array, use a List:

```
@GET("bills/")
Call<List<YourResponse>> getListOfSponsors(....);
```

vs wrong:

```
@GET("bills/")
Call<YourResponse> getListOfSponsors(....);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, worked for me althought I used <ArrayList>.

Answer (score 9):

You can create POJO classes from json response automatically using this link -> [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

All you need to do is paste the JSON response in the edit box given.

1. Select Target language as JAVA,
2. Source type as JSON
3. Annotation style as Gson
4. and check  Use primitive types , include getters and setters, allow additional properties

Comment: You can name the classes as per your conventions.

Comment: I had no idea this existed, even though it makes so much sense. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 3):

Create below class in your model package:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SponsorModel {

 @SerializedName("sponsors")
@Expose
private List<Sponsor> sponsors = null;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

public List<Sponsor> getSponsors() {
    return sponsors;
}

public void setSponsors(List<Sponsor> sponsors) {
    this.sponsors = sponsors;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

-----------------------------------Sponsor.java-----------------------------------

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Sponsor {

@SerializedName("leg_id")
@Expose
private String legId;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("committee_id")
@Expose
private Object committeeId;
@SerializedName("official_type")
@Expose
private String officialType;

public String getLegId() {
    return legId;
}

public void setLegId(String legId) {
    this.legId = legId;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Object getCommitteeId() {
    return committeeId;
}

public void setCommitteeId(Object committeeId) {
    this.committeeId = committeeId;
}

public String getOfficialType() {
    return officialType;
}

public void setOfficialType(String officialType) {
    this.officialType = officialType;
}

}
```

Set above SponsorsModel in your result.

Thanks

Comment: Tried your code but still getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at

Comment: are you sure in your response its start and end with [ ]? your response start with object not array...this is the issue