# How to display json data into the android layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit, retrofit2

MY JSON looks like this. I just need to set these values in the layout of the fragment. So that the details about this product will be displayed.

```
{
  "adid": 5,
  "uid": 1130,
  "userName": "Maëly",
  "cid": 5,
  "brand": null,
  "model": null,
  "title": "Nummular dermatitis",
  "description": "Nam sa dea ss "
  "address": "9795 Debra Center",
  "price": 1544,
  "photo1": "../../../img/mobile/oneplus/3t/3t-1.jpg",
  "photo2": null,
  "photo3": null,
  "photo4": null,
  "ip_add": null,
  "created": 1493921700000,
  "expiryDate": null,
  "published": true,
  "sold": null,
  "featured": true,
  "cond": true,
  "price_neg": true,
  "used_for": "8",
  "views": 1575,
  "city": "Kathmandu",
  "landmark": null,
  "quality": null,
  "alert": null,
  "features": [

  ]
}
```

Comment: Add your code what you tried.

Comment: please refer below link for help [json to refrofit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623437/parse-json-array-response-using-retrofit-gson)

Comment: MuthuKrishnan Sir, I have a pojo class, ApiInterface and ApiClient and a blank fragment with fragment activity to show the results. Some code I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do step that SpaceBison Suggest 
Then do this,
if for e.g. JSONSCHEMATOPOJO create class POJO for you then do this.

```
try{
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(string);
Gson gson= new Gson();
POJO p = gson.fromJson(object,POJO.class)'
}catch(JSONException){
e.printStackStra();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ever had a glance at the Retrofit documentation? http://square.github.io/retrofit/?

You can make synchronous, or asynchonous calls to the service, you create for your interface and do with the result as you please. If you want the data shown in a fragment, you'll probably do an asynchonous call and when you get back the data (which via the Gson converter should automatically be converted from JSON to your data model classes) you can e.g. show the list of data objects in a ListView or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [a Gson converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson). You can generate Gson POJO definitions with [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) - despite the name it also can use an example JSON.

Comment: I have done that already now I am confused how to consume that Json. I have no clue what to do next.