# parsing nested json with retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

How to parsing nested json with retrofit in android?

```
    {
    "204": {
        "input": [
            {
                "name": "nima",
                "school": "alavi",
                "age": 20,
                "scheduled": false
            } 
            }
        ],
        "output": [
            {
                "name": "amin",
                "school": "alavi",
                "age": 24,
                "scheduled": false
            }          
        ],
        "internal": [],
        "external": []
    }
   }
```

I want to read json file in two `recycleview`.

Comment: **`FYI`**  `your JSON is invalid` check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: please post your code

Comment: `retrofit` has nothing to do with JSON. It only does network requests. What is a problem for you to parse this JSON?

Comment: **invalid json** - you have an unexpected `}` inside your `input` array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON array response using Retrofit & Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623437/parse-json-array-response-using-retrofit-gson)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library to parse Json directly into your model class(Java objects). Retrofit is used for to call webservices.

Comment: refer [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"204": {
    "input": [
        {
            "name": "nima",
            "school": "alavi",
            "age": 20,
            "scheduled": false
        } 
        }
    ],
    "output": [
        {
            "name": "amin",
            "school": "alavi",
            "age": 24,
            "scheduled": false
        }          
    ],
    "internal": [],
    "external": []
}
}
```

Your Object Class like this

```
public class [Object Class Name] {
    private ArrayList<Inputs> inputItems;
    private ArrayList<Outputs> outputItems;
    private ArrayList<Internals> internalItems;
    private ArrayList<Externals> externalItems;

    // Getters setters
}

public class Inputs {
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private int age;
    private boolean scheduled;

    // Getters setters
}

public class Outputs {
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private int age;
    private boolean scheduled;

    // Getters setters
}
```

Comment: please help me about fill data in recycle view with retrofit.