# Parsing an array of strings using Retrofit2 for android

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

I am relatively new to retrofit and I have an issue in parsing some string arrays which are a part of a JSON response.

This is the JSON response.

```
{
"positive": [
    "Relaxed",
    "Uplifted",
    "Hungry",
    "Sleepy",
    "Tingly"
],

"medical": [
    "Eye Pressure",
    "Insomnia",
    "Stress",
    "Fatigue",
    "Headaches"
]
}
```

How do I approach this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Create [POJO class](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) then use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623437/parse-json-array-response-using-retrofit-gson

Comment: `List<String>` maybe?

Comment: Create a POJO class which contains two list<String>

Comment: `class myJsonResponse(){
    List<String> positive = new List<String>;
    List<String> medical = new List<String>;
    
    //getters and setters
}`

Comment: My POJO :

        public List<String> getPositive() {
 return positive;
 }

Comment: My MainActivity.java

`public void onResponse(Call<List<Strain>> call, Response<List<Strain>> response) {
               List<Strain> basicDetailsList2 = response.body();

               List<String> positiveTraitsArray = basicDetailsList2.get(checknum).getPositive();
                Log.d("Positive array", "onResponse: " + positiveTraitsArray);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Strain>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error strainCall2 : ", "onFailure: " + t);

            }
        });`

Comment: This is what my logcat tells me : 


`onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into your comments I assume that your POJO class is proper but the way you're using it with Retrofit call is wrong. Make sure that the POJO class is like below,

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Foo {

    @SerializedName("positive")
    @Expose
    private List<String> positive = null;
    @SerializedName("medical")
    @Expose
    private List<String> medical = null;

    public List<String> getPositive() {
        return positive;
    }

    public List<String> getMedical() {
        return medical;
    }

}
```

And use above POJO class like this.

Your API interface

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface FooApiInterface {

    /* pass POJO class to Call<> */

    @GET("request/url")
    Call<Foo> getFoo(/* parameters for the request if there any */);

    /* other api calls here */
}
```

Next use API interface

```
FooApiInterface client = ...;  // initialization

Call<Foo> fooCall = client.getFoo();

fooCall.enqueue(
         new Callback<Foo>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Foo> call, @NonNull Response<Foo> response) {
                 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     List<String> positiveList = response.body().getPositive();
                     List<String> medicalList = response.body().getMedical();
                 }
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Foo> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                     Log.e("error", "API Error ", t);
              }
    }
);
```

Notice that, here I am using `Foo` POJO class as parameter to `Call` instead of `List<Strain>` (like used in your code). If you modify the code as said above, you can get rid of the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ error

For demonstration purpose I used `Foo` example. Change it according to your requirements.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to create POJO class like below

```
public  class  ExampleResponse  {

private  List < String >  positive  =  null;
private  List < String >  medical  =  null;

public  List < String >  getPositive() {
    return  positive;
}

public  void  setPositive(List < String >  positive) {
    this.positive  =  positive;
}

public  List < String >  getMedical() {
    return  medical;
}

public  void  setMedical(List < String >  medical) {
    this.medical  =  medical;
}
```

}

It's working perfectly.

Comment: Trying this only for positive now.

My POJO : 

` private List< String > positive  =  null;

    public List<String> getPositive() {
        return positive;
    }`

Comment: Main Activity : 

` @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Strain>> call, Response<List<Strain>> response) {

                List<Strain> basicDetailsList2 = response.body();
                List<String> positiveTraitsArray = basicDetailsList2.get(0).getPositive();
                Log.d("Positive array", "onResponse: " + positiveTraitsArray);

            }

I still get the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ error :/

Comment: Yep. @Shashanth's and your answer worked. Just had to make slight changes to my pojo. Had to make sure I had a List<String> postive.