# parsing nested json using retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android

How to parse a JSON response using retrofit which looks like this, any help would be greatly appreciated, been stuck with this for a while now.

Update : Below is the code i have tried so far but i am not able to get the data and also i am not able to figure out what is wrong with it, jsonschema2pojo gave me two java classes and that's what i have used in my code. As per my understanding i am supposed to use those two java classes and pass my baseurl as well as endpoint and then calling them in my activity. I have followed the procedures correctly i suppose but have not been successful in retrieving the data so far.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "employee_salary": "320800",
    "employee_age": "61",
    "profile_image": ""
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
private ArrayList<Datum> results;
private EmployeeAdapter employeeAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getEmployees();
}

private void getEmployees() {

    GetEmployeeData getCountryDataService = RetrofitInstance.getService();

    Call<Info> call = getCountryDataService.getResults();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Info>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Info> call, Response<Info> response) {

            Info info = response.body();

            if (info != null && info.getData() != null) {

                results = (ArrayList<Datum>) info.getData();

                viewData();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Info> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private void viewData() {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_countries_list);
    employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(results);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);

}
```

}

Datum.java

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

@SerializedName("employee_name")
@Expose
private String employeeName;


@SerializedName("employee_salary")
@Expose
private String employeeSalary;


@SerializedName("employee_age")
@Expose
private String employeeAge;


@SerializedName("profile_image")
@Expose
private String profileImage;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

public String getEmployeeSalary() {
    return employeeSalary;
}

public void setEmployeeSalary(String employeeSalary) {
    this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
}

public String getEmployeeAge() {
    return employeeAge;
}

public void setEmployeeAge(String employeeAge) {
    this.employeeAge = employeeAge;
}

public String getProfileImage() {
    return profileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}
```

Info.java

```
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;


@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Then the interface i am using is this

GetEmployeeData.java

```
@GET("employees")
Call<Info> getResults();
```

}

RetrofitInstance.java

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static String BASE_URL = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/";

```
public static GetEmployeeData getService() {


    if (retrofit == null) {

        retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }


    return retrofit.create(GetEmployeeData.class);
}
```

Comment: create a model class using the json and access the data

Comment: Similar question - [Parse JSON array response using Retrofit & Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42623437/8498513)

Comment: @Maitri Gave the correct answer. You need to create Model Class (Data Definitions) for Outer and Inner Class (nested JSON) and then pass this model to the Retrofit. You should receive a List of `data` class object (model class) inside the `response` class (Parent model class)

Comment: @Maitri I did create model classes using jsonschema2pojo and tried showing the data in a recycler-view but without any success, also jsonschema2pojo gave me two classes when i used the above json response.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an example how to create a model class. I am doing it in `Kotlin`, but I'm sure you can convert it to `Java` easily.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class EmployeeDTO(
   @SerializedName("id")
   var id: Int,
   @SerializedName("employee_name")
   var name: String,
   @SerializedName("employee_salary")
   var salary: Int,
   @SerializedName("employee_age")
   var age: Int, 
   @SerializedName("profile_image")
   var image: Boolean
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) but jsonschema2pojo gives me two java classes so what about the second class and also how do i call it in my activity?