# RETROFIT2 Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, android, jackson, retrofit

I have some troubles with my call. My callback always return onFailure with this error:

> onResponse: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT
>   token
>        at [Source: okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader@4c32516; line: 1, column: 1]

The API Response farms/abstract (with one item on list):

```
[
    {
        "id": "0fb30c45-00d9-4171-9673-85991dca5db2",
        "name": "Areado"
    }
]
```

This is my Interface:

```
public interface FarmService {

    @GET("farms/abstract")
    Call<ArrayList<FarmList>> getFarmList(@Header("Authorization") String token);
}
```

And this is my method/function:

```
private void callGetFarmList() {
        try {
            Call<ArrayList<FarmList>> call = new RetrofitConfig().getFarmList().getFarmList(authToken);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<FarmList>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<FarmList>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<FarmList>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {

                            int codeResult = response.code();

                            switch (codeResult) {
                                case 200:
                                    farmListArrayList = new ArrayList<FarmList>();
                                    farmListArrayList = response.body();
                                    createFarmRecyclerView();
                                    break;
                                case 201:
                                    /*Created*/
                                    Log.d("201", "onResponse: 201");
                                    break;
                                case 401:
                                    /*Unauthorized*/

                                    break;
                                case 403:
                                    /*Forbidden*/

                                    break;
                                case 404:
                                    /*Error*/

                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Error
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<FarmList>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(FazendaActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("getFarmList", "onResponse: " + t);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("erroGetFarmList", "callGetFarmList: " + e);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

This is my class:

```
public class FarmList {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public FarmList() {
        super();
    }

    public FarmList(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FarmList{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UPDATED 25/05/2020**

I changed to GsonConverterFactory instead JacksonConverterFactory

```
public class RetrofitConfig {
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    public RetrofitConfig() {
        this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("MY_BASE_URL")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public LoginService getLogin() {
        return this.retrofit.create(LoginService.class);
    }

    public FarmService getFarm() {
        return this.retrofit.create(FarmService.class);
    }

    public FarmService getFarmList() {
        return this.retrofit.create(FarmService.class);
    }
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**
The BE send me a new response and now it's working like a charm. But thanks @KasımÖzdemir, for the time to help me

```
{
    "farms": [
        {
            "id": "0fc2b30c-4500-c399-4171-e2809373e280",
            "name": "Areado"
        },
        {
            "id": "81041a28-1193-4310-b616-fabcabdf63d7",
            "name": "Fazenda 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838816/8956604

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir the answer in the other topic is nice, but not solved my problem. This method (farms/abstract) return a farm list, my coworker use the list on iOS and fucntion normal.

Comment: You can respond String instead of ArrayList<FarmList>>. Are you using GsonConverterFactory in RetrofitService?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I'm using JacksonConverterFactory. Only String or a ArrayList<String>?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I changed to GsonConverterFactory instead JacksonConverterFactory and removed the ArrayList, put only the Object (FarmList) and now my response is successefull but my response.body() is null in both parameters (id, name). You know why?

Comment: Why did you remove the ArrayList?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Because if I pass like a ArrayList<FarmList>, the response (throwable) is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: You can try to use string instead ArrayList<FarmList>. Then you can convert string to ArrayList<FarmList> using GSON.

Comment: Everyone used List<FarmList> instead  ArrayList<FarmList>. You can look at [one](https://medium.com/@dds861/json-arrays-parsing-using-retrofit-and-recycleview-9b2d494cc24c) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623437/parse-json-array-response-using-retrofit-gson)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214600/discussion-between-gabriel-junior-de-souza-and-kasim-ozdemir).